# Port apk for ICS for gingerbread

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an app for ICS, I want to make it work on gingerbread, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Set `android:minSdkVersion="9"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, as described in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

And inspect the code to make sure you aren't calling any APIs which are not available in Gingerbread; Lint can help with this. If you are, take appropriate action, such as disabling the relevant functionality or providing alternative implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Start by going into the Project build properties and set the Android SDK version to 2.3 -> 2.37 (sdk 9 or 10).  Eclipse will show you the differences you have to make in order to compile the project.

You're going to have to make some changes to the XML layout files.  There may be some widgets that don't work in Gingerbread.  I'm not sure if those will be apparent until you actually run the app on the device.  But there hopefully shouldn't be too many differences.

Some big code changes would be for example if the app uses Fragments, tools for using screen sizes (re: 7" devices), OpenGL, etc.

I would also skim through these pages before you start:

- http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html
- http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.2.html
- http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html
- http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0.html